# Thread running at User-initiated quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Utility quality-of-service class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

i found this crash in debug window earlier there is no crash but when i upgrade MacOS Sonoma Version 14.4 i started getting this crash in debug window.

```
Thread Performance Checker: Thread running at User-initiated quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Utility quality-of-service class. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions
PID: 9986, TID: 4820737
Backtrace
=================================================================
3   CoreData                            0x00000001a7009e1c 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 85532
4   CoreData                            0x00000001a7008fd0 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 81872
5   CoreData                            0x00000001a7008f64 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 81764
6   CoreData                            0x00000001a7008d68 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 81256
7   CoreData                            0x00000001a70086d8 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 79576
8   CoreData                            0x00000001a70084dc 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 79068
9   CoreData                            0x00000001a700839c 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 78748
10  CoreData                            0x00000001a7008070 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 77936
11  CoreData                            0x00000001a7006790 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 71568
12  CoreData                            0x00000001a70063c8 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 70600
13  CoreData                            0x00000001a70062c0 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 70336
14  CoreData                            0x00000001a70061e0 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 70112
15  NaviagtionSystem-Jatin              0x000000010105ef88 __72-[GMSTileDataCache loadTileForTileCoords:dataVersion:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 508
16  CoreData                            0x00000001a7014f70 383ED744-3910-33E5-A4AB-5C133DD896E5 + 130928
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102e927bc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102e9a66c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 832
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102e9b408 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102ea8404 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 328
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102ea7a38 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 444
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001faec0f20 _pthread_wqthread + 288
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001faec0fc0 start_wqthread + 8
```

i tried to find out this crash in code side there is no crashes i met. one more thing app is working fine on my end.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be linked to GoogleMaps SDK. Check if they have the issue on their repo and/or have a newer version.

Comment: @Larme thanks. but i worked with the same xcode it's working fine but when i installed sonoma 14.4 i started getting that debugger crash without notify by xcode environment as below screenshot