Text-To-Speech: Thread running at User-interactive quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Default quality-of-service class
I created an app with text-to-speech support. And Xcode gave me this "Thread Performance warning" once app is launched or start speak a text, I'm using a real iPhone.
I could use a minimum project to reproduce this issue. Just click play button. And using Xcode 15.3.
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    private let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Taylor Swift")
                
                let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
                
                utterance.voice = voice
                
                synthesizer.speak(utterance)
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Thread Performance Checker: Thread running at User-interactive quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Default quality-of-service class. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions
PID: 718, TID: 60313
Backtrace
=================================================================
3   Foundation                          0x00000001957e5370 31D526A2-AB5C-3B1D-BCA5-B1E082D94712 + 7668592
4   Foundation                          0x0000000195170820 31D526A2-AB5C-3B1D-BCA5-B1E082D94712 + 899104
5   Foundation                          0x00000001951920bc 31D526A2-AB5C-3B1D-BCA5-B1E082D94712 + 1036476
6   TextToSpeech                        0x00000001b74d2268 TTSSpeechTransformTextWithLanguageAndVoiceIdentifier + 5132
7   TextToSpeech                        0x00000001b74d7910 AXAVSpeechSynthesisVoiceFromTTSSpeechVoice + 13132
8   TextToSpeech                        0x00000001b74cd5a8 _TTSIdentifierForVoiceInformation + 8188
9   TextToSpeech                        0x00000001b74cd988 _TTSIdentifierForVoiceInformation + 9180
10  TextToSpeech                        0x00000001b74cd6b0 _TTSIdentifierForVoiceInformation + 8452
11  TextToSpeech                        0x00000001b74d01a8 _TTSIdentifierForVoiceInformation + 19452
12  SpeakyTestApp                       0x0000000102c18594 $s13SpeakyTestApp11ContentViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI6ButtonVyAE0E0PAEE15foregroundStyleyQrqd__AE05ShapeK0Rd__lFQOyAiEE4fontyQrAE4FontVSgFQOyAE5ImageV_Qo__AE5ColorVQo_GyXEfU_yycfU_ + 200
13  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b8d1068 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 25792616
14  SwiftUI                             0x000000019ae33db0 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 14663088
15  SwiftUI                             0x000000019ae39fc4 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 14688196
16  SwiftUI                             0x000000019ae37cc4 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 14679236
17  SwiftUI                             0x000000019ae37c10 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 14679056
18  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b533264 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 22000228
19  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b5325fc 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 21997052
20  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b531fc0 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 21995456
21  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b065914 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 16963860
22  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b06593c 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 16963900
23  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b065914 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 16963860
24  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b8bbebc 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 25706172
25  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b8bc284 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 25707140
26  SwiftUI                             0x000000019ba5690c 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 27388172
27  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b7f6ab0 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 24898224
28  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b7f5078 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 24891512
29  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b7f5204 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 24891908
30  UIKitCore                           0x00000001985de664 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 1459812
31  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198499298 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 127640
32  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198495918 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 112920
33  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198495844 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 112708
34  UIKitCore                           0x000000019867ae54 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 2100820
35  UIKitCore                           0x000000019867a0e4 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 2097380
36  UIKitCore                           0x000000019863c970 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 1845616
37  UIKitCore                           0x000000019863b010 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 1839120
38  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198639a1c 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 1833500
39  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198524d78 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 699768
40  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198524468 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 697448
41  UIKitCore                           0x0000000198524524 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 697636
42  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019623562c 7A70D5D4-0550-38DC-AB33-71B72AFF1F5F + 226860
43  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001962348a8 7A70D5D4-0550-38DC-AB33-71B72AFF1F5F + 223400
44  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000196233058 7A70D5D4-0550-38DC-AB33-71B72AFF1F5F + 217176
45  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000196231d88 7A70D5D4-0550-38DC-AB33-71B72AFF1F5F + 212360
46  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000196231968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
47  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001da52f4e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
48  UIKitCore                           0x00000001986a4edc 86B7C8DD-E910-31BD-B8FE-28962256DEE3 + 2272988
49  UIKitCore                           0x00000001986a4518 UIApplicationMain + 340
50  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b06b860 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 16988256
51  SwiftUI                             0x000000019b06b6a8 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 16987816
52  SwiftUI                             0x000000019ac879fc 9B6AC5DA-C8CE-3B73-8B29-487E9281983F + 12909052
53  SpeakyTestApp                       0x0000000102c19918 $s13SpeakyTestApp0abcC0V5$mainyyFZ + 40
54  SpeakyTestApp                       0x0000000102c199c8 main + 12
55  dyld                                0x00000001b9752d84 960A7452-3178-3C9D-8CE5-FE40FDE8DBC8 + 23940
          IPCAUClient.cpp:129   IPCAUClient: bundle display name is nil


i found same issue and asked question but didn't get any answer. no luck. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78204068/22000500

Well, It seems Xcode's problem since this code is really sample all things are build-in, and idt we need to add mutithreading on AVSpeechSynthesizer in this sample code. I will leave it for now.

Put the AVSpeechSynthesizer inside an object such as an Observable or ObservableObject if you have to support older versions.

@loremipsum it is, this code snippet just a minimum sample to show the issue.

Found any solution on this? @ZhouHaibo
